# Initializing a static const variable gives me template definition of non-template const

Tags: c++

Here is my code :

```
#include <iostream>
class c{
    public:
    int y;
     c(int x,int p):y(x){
    std::cout<<"has been made"<<std::endl;  
    }


};



template<int x,typename B = void>
struct checkeven{

};


template<typename B>
struct checkeven<0,B>{
    typedef B type;
};



template<int x,int y,class = typename checkeven<x%2,int>::type>
struct t{
    static const c tee;

    static const inline c& initor(){

    return tee;
    }
};

template<int x,int y>
const c t<x,y>::tee(x,y);       //how do i initialize?


int main(int argc, char** argv) {

 //t<2,1>::initor();    
//t<2,2>::initor(); 

    return 0;
}
```

I tried researching it about but i can't find anything except the suggestion to remove the default value duplicate. I want to implement SFINAE to make sure that the first value is an even number. I have a static const variable that i want to initialize. It was working fine without my default class but once i added it, things got messy. How do i initialize my const static member? I would also like to know why my code isn't working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specialize your template struct `t` like that :

```
template<int x, int y>
struct t<x,y, typename checkeven<x%2,int>::type> 
{
    static const c tee;

    static const inline c& initor(){

        return tee;
    }
};
```

Using this you'll be able to initialize your variable tee like that :

```
template<int x, int y>
const c t<x, y>::tee(x, y);
```

Live example [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1fad8f4aa63380a8)

Comment: @CarloBrew I tried this by instinct, I'm looking for the reason in the standard, I'll edit my post as soon as I have a valid reason.

Comment: Actually, i tried this too and it worked, i kept everything the same from my original code but i added this line instead of the one i posted. `template<int x, int y, class B>
const c t<x, y, B>::tee(x, y);` I have to give a name for class though. I think the specialization was needed because it's unnamed.

Comment: With this line that's normal that you had to add the type of class B. But as you I can't understand why the compiler did not choose the struct `t` with `checkeven<x%2,int>::type` as a default template argument

Comment: @CarloBrew I Checked in the standard but I can't find why it didn't work. I am going to ask a question on SO, with a link to your question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84247/discussion-between-pumkko-and-carlo-brew).