# Template struct with the default template argument is not instantiated

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization, default-arguments

Let's say I have this code

```
template<typename T2, typename T = int>
struct X
{
    static double f;
};

template<typename T>
double X<T>::f = 14.0;
```

If I try to compile clang give me the following error

> nested name specifier 'X::' for declaration does not refer into a
>   class, class template or class template partial specialization

and for GCC :

> error: template definition of non-template 'double X::f'

The question is :

Why the compiler want us to specialize the struct X like that :

```
template<typename T2>
struct X<T2,int>
{
    static double f;
};
```

The first declaration has `int` as a default argument, why the compiler don't choose this declaration ?

I searched in the [standard](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2015/n4527.pdf) anchor [temp.spec] but it didn't help.

I ask this question after answered this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31623570/5076707) on SO.

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"Why the compiler want us to specialize the struct X like that" - that's not what the error messages are saying. You don't *need* to do this, and you really shouldn't do it unless what you want is a partial specialization and a static member defined only for that partial specialization.

The problem is that `template<typename T2, typename T = int> struct X` is a class template that has *two* template parameters. The fact that the second one has a default template argument doesn't change the fact that there are still two parameters.

So, you need to define your class template member as belonging to a class template with two parameters, like this:

```
template<typename T2, typename T>
double X<T2, T>::f = 14.0;
```

The relevant paragraphs in the standard (N4527, the current draft):

[14.5.1p3]

> When a member function, a member class, a member enumeration, a static
>   data member or a member template of a class template is defined
>   outside of the class template definition, the member definition is
>   defined as a template definition in which the *template-parameters* are
>   those of the class template. The names of the template parameters used
>   in the definition of the member may be different from the template
>   parameter names used in the class template definition. The template
>   argument list following the class template name in the member
>   definition shall name the parameters in the same order as the one used
>   in the template parameter list of the member. Each template parameter
>   pack shall be expanded with an ellipsis in the template argument list.

[14.1p9]

> [...] A default *template-argument* shall not be specified in the
>   *template-parameter-lists* of the definition of a member of a class
>   template that appears outside of the member’s class. [...]

---

As specified in the quote above, the actual names of the template parameters (`T2` and `T`) don't matter, they can be different from the ones in the class template definition, but they need to be consistent within the definition of the member. That is, you can do this

```
template<typename T, typename U>
double X<T, U>::f = 14.0;
```

and it will still define the member of the correct `X` class template. However, using the same names can make things easier to understand when reading the code.

---

By defining the partial specialization before the definition of `f` in your original example, `template<typename T> double X<T>::f = 14.0;` becomes a valid definition of the member `f` of the partial specialization `template<typename T2> struct X<T2,int>`, and only of that template (partial specializations are templates themselves). The member `f` of the primary template `template<typename, typename> struct X` remains undefined.

The relevant wording is in [14.5.5.3p1]:

> The template parameter list of a member of a class template partial
>   specialization shall match the template parameter list of the class
>   template partial specialization. The template argument list of a
>   member of a class template partial specialization shall match the
>   template argument list of the class template partial specialization. A
>   class template specialization is a distinct template. The members of
>   the class template partial specialization are unrelated to the members
>   of the primary template. [...]

Comment: I did not do it just to silence the compiler error. I thought that the OP did not want to explictly specify the second template parameter which has a default value in the declaration. However I can't understand why in the default value is not used when we define the static member. In other words why it is irrevelant ?

Comment: @Pumkko Think about this: assuming that your version of the definition of `f` worked, what would you expect to happen if you used `X<char, long>::f` somewhere in your code?

Comment: @bogdan I think the linker would complain. If the definition of f with the default value had worked, we would have only defined a `X<T, int>::f`  assuming that `int` was the default type. No definition for X<char,long>

Comment: @Pumkko Exactly. So, you didn't define a member of the template `template<typename, typename> struct X`. You tried to define a member of a different template, and that template is not defined itself.

Comment: It looks like @dyp read between the lines of your question better than I did - you were indeed intending to define a member of a class template partial specialization without defining the partial specialization itself (partial specializations are templates themselves). Anyway, everything in the answer still stands, maybe I should try to add some clarification related to partial specializations.

Comment: @Pumkko I've updated the answer with what I think are the relevant parts of the comments above.

Comment: maybe a good way of depicting that phenomenon is to underline that default argument don't generate the sister class with 1 template parameter. Though, that's how functions work. Default argument in functions generate a sister function overload with a smaller arity. From that behavior, we expect the same to happen for class templates. And it appears that it does not. Such a sister class would be a specialization, and it has to be manually declared. Am I correct ?

Comment: @v.oddou Function default arguments don't generate any overloads. If you have `void f(int, int = 7);`, `f(3)` is just another way of writing `f(3, 7)`. It calls the exact same function; no new overloads are introduced. Trying to do `void (*p)(int) = f;` will fail (it would succeed if you actually had a `void f(int);` overload). The first declaration declares just one function taking two parameters; `void (*p)(int, int) = f;` will succeed. Default template arguments work similarly enough in this respect: a little bit more than syntax sugar, but not much more.

Comment: noted ! the pointer access is an excellent thought experiment to depict that no new symbol is introduced. thanks.

Comment: @v.oddou Cheers! For completeness, I think there's one more example worth giving, since it's one other case where it may look like some functions with fewer parameters are involved: during overload resolution. Given `void f(int, long = 7);`, `void f(long, int = 3);`, and the call `f(3)`, both overloads are viable candidates, and the overload resolution process will only look at the parameters for which the call has arguments *as written*, that is, only the first parameter for each function. The first overload wins and is called with the arguments `(3, 7)`.

Comment: If, however, you write the second argument explicitly in the call, `f(3, 7)`, both parameters of both functions will be considered during overload resolution, and the call will fail as ambiguous. Still, this is only about the lists of parameters that overload resolution uses to determine the best overload; only the two functions are involved in all cases, no others.