# Template class definition with enable_if causes error

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, enable-if

Can someone please help me to understand why the following code does not compile and also help me to fix it:

```
template< size_t N_1, size_t N_2, typename callable, typename T_out = typename std::result_of<callable>::type, size_t N = N_1 - N_2, std::enable_if_t< N_1>=N_2>* = nullptr>
class A
{
  template<std::size_t... I>
  void foo();
};


template< size_t N_1, size_t N_2, typename callable >
template<std::size_t... I>
void A< N_1, N_2, callable>::foo()
{
}
```

Error:

```
error: nested name specifier 'A<N_1, N_2, callable>::' for declaration does not refer into a class, class template or class template partial specialization
    void A< N_1, N_2, callable>::foo()
         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
1 error generated.
```

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Though a much more trivial example, [see this question and answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31625178/1322972).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A definition of a template declaration needs to match the declaration. The `std::enable_if_t` does throw a curveball here, but this seems to work with gcc 6.2:

```
template< size_t N_1, size_t N_2, typename callable, typename T_out, size_t N,
      std::enable_if_t< N_1 >= N_2> *p>
template<std::size_t... I>
void A< N_1, N_2, callable, T_out, N, p>::foo()
{
}
```

Comment: Many thanks! Do you know why the arguments for the template parameters `T_out`, `N` and the `enable_if` must be stated explicitly and are not chosen automatically by using their default values?

Comment: The short answer is "that's how C++ works". If the class's template was only `template< size_t N_1, size_t N_2=N_1> class A`, you'll have the same problem if you were to define `template< size_t N_1> template<std::size_t... I> void A< N_1>::foo()`. You must list all template parameters when defining something in the template: `template< size_t N_1, size_t N_2>
template<std::size_t... I> void A< N_1, N_2 >::foo()`.

Comment: Am I wrong when I say that this characteristic of C++ "requiring arguments for all template parameters even when default values are stated" is against intuition?

Comment: They are required when defining the template. The defaults are for when the template is used, somewhere...